# Java Web Start Error: "There is no defined launch URL property, invalid webstart file"

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Attempting to execute a Java webstart applet (samclientdesktop.jnlp) for execution of the Alcatel-Lucent 5620 SAM environment on MacOS 10.9.5, running Java 8. This .jnlp appears to function without fault, and without editing required, in Windows XP/Vista/7.

Have managed to work through a multitude of parameter changes to get to this point, where I am now encountering a message that states: `There is no defined launch URL property, invalid webstart file.`

The debug log shows the following entry: `SEVERE: Invalid JNLP file, there must by(sīc) a launch.url system property.`

I have added the filepath for the .jnlp file, local working path, URL path to the java applet, and the IP of the server to the Java exceptions list. I've tried adjusting the launch.url value to various values (local filepath, wildcard, alternate server). No dice. Welcome any ideas, at this point.

EDIT:
Was asked to provide full .jnlp file contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  SAM Client launch with desktop link. -->
<jnlp spec="1.5+" version="8.0" codebase="http://`*hidden*`/samcommandservlet/" href="samclientdesktop.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>5620 SAM Client</title>
        <vendor>Alcatel-Lucent Canada</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.alcatel-lucent.com"/>
        <description>5620 SAM Client</description>
        <description kind="short">5620 SAM Client</description>
        <description kind="tooltip">5620 SAM Client</description>
        <icon kind="splash" href="images/alcatel_logo_1_SAM_10_0_R7.gif"/>
        <icon href="images/SAM_Desktop_16_16_SAM_10_0_R7.gif" width="16" height="16"/>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="images/SAM_Desktop_16_16_SAM_10_0_R7.gif" width="16" height="16"/>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="images/SAM_Desktop_32_32_SAM_10_0_R7.gif" width="32" height="32"/>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="images/SAM_Desktop_64_64_SAM_10_0_R7.gif" width="64" height="64"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="false">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="5620 SAM Client"/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <property name="launch.url" value="http://`*hidden*`/samcommandservlet/samclientdesktop.jnlp"/> 
        <j2se version="1.8" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="512m"/>
        <jar href="nms_wsclient.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
        <jar href="commons-httpclient.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="commons-codec.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="commons-logging.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="log4j.jar" download="eager"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.timetra.nms.client.launcher.WebStartLaunchPoint">
        <argument>-server</argument>
        <argument>`*hidden*`;`*hidden*`</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Apart from having adjusted the initial memory heap size and the version of Java that is running (without which I wouldn't have even gotten to the error message I'm experiencing), this is the default file generated by the server.

Comment: What does the full JNLP file look like?

Comment: @markspace added the full .jnlp contents to the question.

Comment: What version of Java have you been running on your Windows machines?  There have been plenty of breaking "improvements" to the security settings in various 1.7/1.8 JDK/JRE updates.  Offhand, it sounds like you might somehow be running afoul of the rules for "secure" properties - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources

Comment: So far, I haven't encountered a version of JRE for Windows that stops this applet from running. I have various client machines ranging between versions 6 through 8. My go-to "golden version" for some legacy apps is 6.26 on Windows, but in this case it doesn't seem to matter which version I use on the Mac. Version 8 has gotten me further than all of the rest (even getting me past the oh-so-often-encountered "missing required permissions manifest attribute in main jar" error)